# Linux: Extract a specified number of lines from text file based on match

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, copy

I have a text file with multiple datasets. I have written a code that searches for certain values (top left 4-letter code) in a text file but, now I need to be able to have the script copy out data from a set number of lines AFTER the match ("PHHI, etc") is found. The data values are all formatted the same.

Data:

```
PHHI   GFS MOS GUIDANCE    7/13/2015  0000 UTC                      
DT /JULY 13            /JULY 14                /JULY 15          /  
HR   06 09 12 15 18 21 00 03 06 09 12 15 18 21 00 03 06 09 12 18 00 
X/N                    83          71          84          70    84
TMP  77 76 76 76 76 79 82 81 76 76 74 73 76 80 82 81 76 75 73 76 83 
DPT  72 72 72 72 72 72 70 68 70 70 69 69 69 70 70 69 69 69 69 69 69 
CLD  BK OV BK OV OV BK FW FW CL FW BK FW SC SC FW FW FW CL FW SC FW 
WDR  10 09 06 04 07 09 07 08 07 06 03 03 07 08 07 08 07 07 04 07 08 
WSP  04 03 03 03 06 11 16 11 06 08 05 03 04 09 12 09 05 03 03 03 10 
P06         5    27    16     0     4     2     4    15     5  6  1 
P12              39          21           8          19        7    
Q06         0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  0  0 
Q12               1           1           0           1        0    
CIG   5  4  4  4  4  4  5  8  6  6  6  7  6  6  7  8  7  8  8  8  8 
VIS   7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7 
OBV   N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N  N
```

I am interested in pulling the data values located on the "X/N" line.

Comment: You only need data from that *one* line after the line you have matched? Or you need all the data *between* those lines? What do you have for this already?

Comment: `am interested in pulling the data values located on the "X/N" line` or  `I need to be able to have the script copy out data from a set number of lines AFTER the match` which is it? clarification needed

Comment: I am currently using    sites="/home/weather/northeast.delimited" egrep -nf ${sites} cy.00.txt > mos.out to match the four-character data values (PHHI). Once the match is made, I need to copy out the entire "X/N" line, which is four lines down from the four-letter data value (PHHI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a specified number of line of data after the match:

```
grep pattern -A num file
```

where,

`pattern` is the pattern to be matched
`num` is the number of line of data to be taken after the match

For example, to get 3 lines after the `PHHI`:

```
grep "^PHHI" -A 3 file
```

Output:

```
PHHI   GFS MOS GUIDANCE    7/13/2015  0000 UTC                      
DT /JULY 13            /JULY 14                /JULY 15          /  
HR   06 09 12 15 18 21 00 03 06 09 12 15 18 21 00 03 06 09 12 18 00 
X/N                    83          71          84          70    84
```

To get only the `X/N` line:

```
grep "^X/N.*" file
```

Output:

```
X/N                    83          71          84          70    84
```

Comment: How can I export each of the matched sites (including 3 lines after the match) to separate text files?

Comment: @AaronPerry redirect the output to a separate file ( `>separate_file`). e.g: `grep "^X/N.*" file >separate_file.txt`